# Cómo alinear una imagen con dos líneas de texto

Tags: html, css

Quiero alinear una imagen con dos líneas de texto, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De hecho, exactamente eso es lo que quiero lograr. Intenté usar vertical align, display: block, margin: 0 auto, etc.

Mi estructura es así  [IMAGEN][SPAN CLASS="TITULO"] Texto aquí [/SPAN][SPAN CLASS="HORA"]19:20[/SPAN]

Y éste es el código:

```
<div class="contenedor"> 
  <img class="fotodeperfil">Nombre Apellido <i class="im im-more-vert"></i> 
  <div class="contenido">Aquí el contenido de la publicación</div> 
  <div class="opciones"><i class="im im-share"></i></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: ¿puedes agregar tu código html y css?

Comment: Puedes añadir tu codigo??

Comment: @Risa__B 
No puedo poner el código porque el edito de texto no me deja poner tantos caracteres, pero para que des una idea de como es es mi código, te paso una imagen https://imgur.com/a/i37Lf

Comment: @ReneLimon Cómo le dije a Risa_B, no puedo poner el código porque el editor de texto no me deja poner tantos caracteres, así es el resultado, no sé si te ayude esto. La verdad no me importa que hayan cambios en la estructura y el diseño, siempre y cuando sea el mismo o mejor resultado [enlace] (https://imgur.com/a/i37Lf)

Comment: si son muchos caracteres reduce el código a [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ReneLimon
<div class="contenedor">
  <img class="fotodeperfil">Nombre Apellido <i class="im im-more-vert"></i>
  <div class="contenido">Aquí el contenido de la publicación</div>
  <div class="opciones"><i class="im im-share"></i></div>
</div>

Comment: @EstebanFernández edita tu pregunta dando click [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/100410/edit) y de paso no olvides dar el [tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) al sitio

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar Flex:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width : auto;
  height : 80px;
  max-width : 250px;
  max-height : 80px;
  background : #f7f7f7;
  display : flex;
  align-items : center;
  justify-content : start;
  padding : 0px 10px;
}

.container-image {
  border-radius : 40px;
  width : 40px;
  height : 40px;
}

.container-body {
  display : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  height : 100%;
  flex : 1;
  padding-left : 5px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-body p {
  margin : 2px;
}

.name {
  color : #0909ff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.date {
  opacity : 0.3;
  font-size : 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<div class="container">
  <!--
  Primer div contenedor
  -->
  
  <!-- imagen -->
  <img 
    src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/12745790_10207082328171097_3738874538662914612_n.jpg?oh=b1c15ae86c2c2cc0a009011f430d7cb1&oe=5A512307"
  
    class="container-image" 
  />
  <div class="container-body">
    <!--
      El contenedor de los nombres y la fecha
      hacemos que su width se ajuste y relleno el espacio sobrante con la propiedad flex : 1;
      Utilizamos :   align-items: flex-start;
                     justify-content: center;
      para llevar el contenido a la izquierda y centrarlo vericalmente
    -->
    <p class="name">Jose Hermosilla</p>
    <p class="date">6 de Septiembre a las 22:32<p>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, es lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Yo no soy mucho de desarrollo front-end, lo que sí te puedo decir es que de esta forma: `[IMAGEN][SPAN CLASS="TITULO"] Texto aquí [/SPAN][SPAN CLASS="HORA"]19:20[/SPAN]`jamás funcionaría, me imagino que obtienes todo en una sola línea, ¿cierto?

Yo lo que haría es crear una tabla de una fila y dos columnas. Y en la segunda columna trabajarías con dos filas. No sé si me explico.

Algo tipo:

```
<div id="table">
    <div id="row">
        <div id="column">
            <!-- Acá insertas tu imagen -->
        </div>

        <div id="column">
            <!-- Acá acomodas el texto en dos líneas como más lo prefieras -->
            <!-- Puedes usar otra tabla (dos filas y una columna), o dos div y un salto de línea entre ambos, etc... Acá tienes muchas opciones.-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sí, ya lo intentaré pero creo que tengo que crear una grid con css

Answer (score 0):

Considera distribución para Imagen, Nombre, Fecha e icono_mundo en el html:

```css
.contenedor{
    font-family:Arial;
 max-width:240px;
 max-height:50px;
 background-color:#B3B3B3;
 padding:5px;   
}
.contenedor div{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
.contenedor .img{width:25%;text-align:center}
.contenedor .img img{border-radius:50%;border:1px solid #9E9E9E;width:48px;height:48px;}
.contenedor .textos{width:70%;}
.contenedor .textos .nombre{font-weight:bold;color:#263E7E;font-size:16px;}
.contenedor .textos .fecha{color:#6F686E;font-size:12px;}
.contenedor .textos .mundo{margin-top:3px;}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
    <div class="img"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkB3N.png?s=48&amp;g=1" alt="" width="48" height="48"></div>
    <div class="textos">
        <div class="nombre">Julio Cesar</div>
        <div class="fecha">
            <div>06 de Setiembre a las 4:16</div>
            <div class="mundo"><img alt="Embedded Image" width="13px" src=" data:image/png;base64,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" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con unos ligeros cambios en tu estructura HTML, podrías utilizar lo siguiente:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  max-width: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
}

.image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.info {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.info .title,
.info .date {
  display: block;
}

.info .title {
  color: #1b3565;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info .date {
  color: #8a7c7e;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="imagen de prueba">
  </figure>
  <p class="info">
    <span class="title">Adore Delano</span>
    <span class="date">23 de agosto a las 16:19</span>  
  </p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, he intentado con todos los códigos y con ninguno me va bien, también he intentado mezclaros, pero no sirve, éste es el resultado que obtengo  https://imgur.com/a/20LE1